# Django Admin: Add <select multiple> to the *other* model in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a many-to-many relationship in my application between `Tools` and `Tasks`. Right now the many-to-many relationship is defined on the `Task` model, such that in the `Task` edit page of the admin I have a `<select multiple>` control that allows you to pick 0 or more `Tools` to associate with the `Task`.

I know that Django does not allow you to define the relationship on both models, but is it still possible to tell the admin to include a `<select multiple>` on the `Tool` edit page as well? I would like to be able to edit the relationship from either side of it.

Comment: You can edit the admin form(set) and extend the save method? select multiple is just a widget, nothing special

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work (given m2m is specified in `Tool`):

```
# 1st app
from secondapp.models import Tool

class Task(models.Model):
    tools = models.ManyToManyField(Tool, through=Tool.tasks.through)

# 2nd app
class Tool(models.Model):
    tasks = models.ManyToManyField("firstapp.Task")
```

Comment: My two models are in two different apps, so how would you avoid the circular import with this? (BTW it's Tasks and Tools, not Tags and Tools.)

Comment: I updated answer to handle different apps and naming :) did not try it but I think this should work.

Comment: It's a good thought but it won't work for me. The m2m is defined in Task, which by your logic would mean I should move the import of app1.Task into app2.models. However, app1 references app2.Tool in other places as well, so I can't move the import as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a dummy model between `Tools` and `Tasks` that acts as an intermediary, something Django offers normally for use in storing extra information about a particular relationship.  You would use the `through=` keyword when creating this `ManyToMany` relationship to make use of that.

You can find details on that [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany).

I haven't actually taken a look at it on the admin page, but I would imagine once you register the model on the admin page, because that model has a `ForeignKey` relationship to *each* of `Tools` and `Tasks`, you should be able to edit the relationship on both sides from the dummy model.

I wouldn't necessarily recommend this, though, unless it's super essential that you be able to access the relationship on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use `through` or complicate your model just for the sake of getting the admin to look fine.  You may alternatively try [creating an admin inline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin).  With inlines, you can add subsections to any model's screen in the admin application.  There are some good examples in the docs.